# MyBatis : Catch message throw stored procedure from SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, spring, stored-procedures, mybatis

I am working with Spring, MyBatis and Microsoft SQL Server. In my project, I need to call a procedure from MyBatis **mapper xml** file.

So, I did it like follow:

```
<select id="callProcedure" parameterType="TestBean" statementType="CALLABLE" >
    {CALL callprocedure(#{id},#{regId})}
</select>
```

And, this is working well. Later, I added **`THROW`** statements in my stored procedure as shown below:

```
THROW 50002, "Invalid Parameters", 1;
```

And, I catch Exception in **my DAO java class** as follow:

```
try {
    myMapper.callProcedure(testBean);
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}
```

That, the main problem is here. When print out the message, it shown so many lines and causes. Not only the message what I throw. I only want the message what I throw.

I cannot get the message which I throw from the procedure by calling `e.getMessage()`.

This show the following messages:

```
org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException: 
### Error querying database.  Cause:com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Invalid Parameters
### The error may exist in mybatis/mapper/application/test.xml
### The error may involve com.test.core.mapper.application.TestMapper.callProcedure-Inline
### The error occurred while setting parameters
### SQL: {CALL callprocedure(?,?)}
### Cause: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Invalid Parameters; uncategorized SQLException for SQL []; SQL state [S0001]; error code [50002]; Invalid Parameters; nested exception is com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Invalid Parameters
...
```

I am trouble with this to get throw message from procedure. How can I solve this?

Or is any other way to working like that? Please, help me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, I got my answer. When I try as follow, I got my message.

```
try {
    myMapper.callProcedure(testBean);
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println(e.getCause().getMessage());
}
```

This solved my problem.